# How to make bootstrap labels inline with scrolling x overflow within a bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/bnb34kzm/ .

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
        <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /btn-group -->
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

I tried "white-space", "display:inline", etc. But in general, once I make the labels inline, they overflow the bootstrap column div. I couldn't find a way to restrict the width of div.input-group, while keeps it being a single line containing the div.form-control and div.input-group-btn.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in your html after `.input-group` class.

```
<div type="text" class="form-control" style="display: inline-block;overflow: auto;"></div>
```